# The "oldest" sort order only works for the first page

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

On [Area 51](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#Area_51), the "oldest" sort order only works for the first page. Clicking on "next" (or "2", "3", etc.) opens a page sorted by *votes*, not by descending age of the examplary questions. The links have `tab=votes` in them. When will this problem be fixed?

NB: the "my votes" and "active" tabs seem to have the same problem. It seems to be limited to Area 51 (at least it works on Stack Overflow) and may or may not have been introduced with [the recent change on Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3038/announcement-changes-to-area-51-voting).

Example: proposal [Home Theater](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2274/home-theater?tab=oldest#tab-top).

[image: Annotated screen dump illustrating the "&tab=votes" links from an "oldest" sort order page.]

Comment: @Arjan 5: yes, the (extreme) lower left and lower right needs some editing to be pixel perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good catch – the current tab wasn't being maintained when paging through example questions. It's fixed now.